# "Advantage of" or "Advantages of"

Tags: grammatical-number

In the following sentence, should it be "has the advantage of" OR "has the advantages of?".  The former looks correct to me, but I'm not sure of the grammatical reason for this.

Magnetic resonance imaging has the advantage of being noninvasive and not involving exposure to radiation, when compared to computerized tomography.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence claims MRI has **two advantages** over CT, namely:

> - it is non-invasive
> - it doesn't involve exposure to radiation

and so the correct sentence is;

> Magnetic resonance imaging has the advantages of being non-invasive and not involving exposure to radiation, when compared to computerized tomography.